# Android - Service, setup time

Tags: android, service, timer

How to setup service to something (api request) everyday at particular time.
I dont know.
Right now I thing about two options:
1. Setup timer and every hour check the time and if it right, do a request.
2. setup the alarm, by alarmManager, but I dont know how to do it.

Another imported thing is the request must be a little random. 
About 3-10 minutes, to prevent blocking the server by too many
request at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) for scheduling events with an `AlarmManager`.
For the interval of 3-10 minutes you could just add something like

```
int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 * 60 * 7 + 3 * 60 * 1000);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + rand, sender);
```

Comment: by setting the alarm manager it will run some intent at every time, how to put/run the method in it?

Comment: Instead of starting an Activity as mentioned in the link, you could start a Service and run your method in the background.

Comment: You know maybe how to set up that alarm will do it twice a day?

Comment: Set up the alarm with an interval of 12 hours. Then, in the Activity or Service that is called by the alarm set the alarm again in 12 hours.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I need alarms, one about 9-11 and second 17-18... is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean with 9-11 and 17-18? Hours? Just create a `Calender` with these settings and set the alarm. You could check for the interval farthest away (i.e. it is 9:00, so the alarm for 17:00 would be farther away than the alarm for 9:00)

Comment: ow , really sorry mate, I found it. I just didn't change the id of second intent. thanks for help.